# deletion with LINQ to SQL in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL in visual studio to interact with my database. Now I added methods that add, change etc to my code, but I cant make removing a row work. here is my remove method:

```
public bool removeUser(User toBeRemoved)
{
    try
    {
        theDBDataContext db = new theDBDataContext();
        UserDB u = new UserDB();
        u.username = toBeRemoved.userName;
        u.password = toBeRemoved.password;
        u.role = toBeRemoved.role;
        db.UserDBs.DeleteOnSubmit(u);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.writelog("Cannot Access DB");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide that function "DeleteOnSubmit(u)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must attach the entity before delete:

```
    theDBDataContext db = new theDBDataContext();
    UserDB u = new UserDB();
    u.username = toBeRemoved.userName;
    u.password = toBeRemoved.password;
    u.role = toBeRemoved.role;
    db.Orders.Attach(u, false);
    db.UserDBs.DeleteOnSubmit(u);
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

See [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.itable.attach(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: And you can also **Select** the entity from db.

Comment: @CihanYakar Which would mean a second query which is not needed.

Comment: @DavidG totally right for this scenario. But, when you enabled concurrency check via properties, and when UserDB class has any property expect username & password this method will not delete anything.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use extension method of Linq to delete the records.**

```
    theDBDataContext db = new theDBDataContext();
     UserDB u = db.UserDBs.Where(u=>(u.username == toBeRemoved.userName & u.password == toBeRemoved.password & u.role==toBeRemoved.role)).FirstOrDefault(); 
     db.UserDBs.DeleteOnSubmit(u);
     db.SubmitChanges();
```